# XAMPP Administrator Password Reset

Tags: windows, wordpress, xampp, bitnami

I'm trying to install WordPress onto my Portable XAMPP-lite with Bitnami. However I get this dialog asking for the administrator password and I have no idea what it is. I never set one up and I've tried all my normal passwords.

I have a Windows machine and all the resets I've found a for Mac/Linux or are outdated. Is there anyway I can reset the password or at least another way to install WordPress?

**Dialog:**

[image]

Comment: Just a guess,It ask you enter twice so maybe its asking you to set a password for later use

Comment: @wen As I said, I have tried every password I use. If it was setting one, I would get past that screen straight away.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but running the installer with elevated rights (Right-click: "Run with elevated rights") fixed it.

It must be asking for an OS admin password; but in a weird way.

Answer (score 0):

when I entered my OS X admin password, it said that it will restart with admin rights, and on the second run, it skipped asking that password and came to this setup stage :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That step is asking for your system password.

- In case of Linux/Mac, that password is your user administrative password. You can also run the installer on the command line with sudo.
- In Windows, you can avoid that step running the installer with Administrator permissions (double click over the installer and clicking on **Run as administrator**)

After that as onur-surme pointed you will be asked for the application password. There you can set the application administrator password, in case of Wordpress the one you use to log in on the back end interface.